# Select users that have an action on two different days with one of those days being within the last week

Tags: mysql, sql

Given an `event_stream` table that looks like this

```
*----*--------*---------*-------------*
| id | action | user_id | occurred_on |
*----*--------*---------*-------------*
```

and a `users` table that looks like this (simplified)

```
*----*-------*
| id | email | 
*----*-------*
```

I want to select all users that have have at least two activities in the `events` table that occurred on different days. In addition, one of those activities needs to have occurred with the last 7 days.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT x.`email` 
  FROM (
      SELECT u.`email`, CAST(e.`occurred_on` AS DATE) d
        FROM `users` u
        JOIN `event_stream` e
             ON e.`user_id` = u.`id`
    GROUP BY CAST(e.`occurred_on` AS DATE), u.`email`
  ) x
GROUP BY x.`email`
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This should give me all users that have activities logged on at least two different days. Now I'm not quite sure how to add my other constraint that of those activities, one of them has to have happened within the last 7 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by user_id and count conditionally:

```
select * 
from users
where id in
(
  select user_id
  from event_stream
  group by user_id
  having count(distinct date(occurred_on)) > 1 -- at least on two different days
     and sum(occurred_on >= current_date - interval 7 day) > 0 -- one in last seven days
);
```

In MySQL true = 1, false = 0, so we can sum a boolean expression in order to count how often it matches.

If `occurred_on` is already a date as the name suggests, not a datetime or timestamp, you can change `count(distinct date(occurred_on))` to `count(distinct occurred_on)`.

Comment: That did it. Thank you. That's also a much simpler query than the one I came up with.

Answer (score 1):

Add one more condition in `having`.

```
SELECT x.`email` 
  FROM (
      SELECT u.`email`, CAST(e.`occurred_on` AS DATE) d
        FROM `users` u
        JOIN `event_stream` e
             ON e.`user_id` = u.`id`
    GROUP BY CAST(e.`occurred_on` AS DATE), u.`email`
  ) x
GROUP BY x.`email`
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND SUM(DATEDIFF(now(),d)>=0 AND DATEDIFF(now(),d)<=7) > 0
```

`DATEDIFF(now(),d)>=0 AND DATEDIFF(now(),d)<=7` evaluates to 1 or 0 depending on the condition being true or false.